# Shimano WH-RS80 Hub measurments

Tags: shimano, hub

Where I can locate the measurements for a Shimano FH-RS80 hub? They were used on the early C20-30 wheels from Shimano, usually Ultegra-labeled with Dura Ace wheels, and some were off road Deore. The shops in my area do not want to give me or sell me the info because they know I build my own wheels.

Comment: If you have the hub, you make the measurements yourself. It isn't hard!

Comment: You could ask a question "how do i measure my hub to get the values i need for my spoke calculator" if that's the problem.

Comment: @Noise Did you [look at the hub design](https://www.google.com/search?q=shimano+wh-rs80+hub&tbm=isch)?  Both hubs use straight-pull spokes, and the rear hub doesn't have a flange at all - it literally has asymmetric lugs projecting out for the spokes to pass through.  Even if one **could** measure it, the leading and trailing spokes on the rear hub attach at different offsets so it's **impossible** to "get the values i need for my spoke calculator".

Comment: @AndrewHenle I disagree.

Comment: @Noise Well then post an answer, explain how it's done, and we can all vote on it.

Answer (score 2):

The Shimano Technical Documents portion of the Shimano website is where to find most of the information you are looking for. The link to search on the WH-RS80 wheel is here: [WH-RS80 Tech Document Search](https://si.shimano.com/en/manual/search?input_model=wh-rs80)

Look at the various Dealer's Manuals (DM), User's Manuals (UM), Service Instructions (SI), and Exploded Views (EV) to gain clues to the specific answers you need.

I found spoke types and lengths in these documents, and they vary depending on the spoke count for the wheel(s) you are needing the specs on.

I cannot find a FH-RS80 referenced on the Shimano site, or in a standard web search either, so the specific hub is possibly identified by a different number.

Comment: FWIW, the hubs look extremely similar to those used on the WH-6700 wheelset.